# indexOf function on dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with a column of type String. I want to get another column with a part of the chain, defined by the position of the character "-".

Example: The column has the value YX-1F2 and I want to get YX as a column.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 application_rules.where((application_rules("apprul_cd_fare_basis").contains("-")===true) && (application_rules("apprul_cd_fare_basis").startsWith("-")===false) && (application_rules("apprul_cd_fare_basis").endsWith("-")===false))
 .select(application_rules("apprul_cd_fare_basis"), application_rules("apprul_cd_fare_basis").substr(0, application_rules("apprul_cd_fare_basis").toString().indexOf("-")))
 .show()
```

But this does not work for me because I always the indexOf("-") function returns -1. Any idea what is my fault and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem:

```
application_rules("apprul_cd_fare_basis").toString().indexOf("-")
```

The `toString()` function here returns you the **title** of selected column, which is `apprul_cd_fare_basis` here. It is not the value you expected. So `indexOf("-")` is not searching in the value but in the column title.

**Solution**

If you just want to add a column with extracted part from the string (for example, `YX` from `YX-1F2`), you could simply do this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.substring_index

application_rules.withColumn(
    "newColumnName",
    substring_index(application_rules("apprul_cd_fare_basis"), "-", 1)
    )
```

**Result**

```
+--------------------+-------------+
|apprul_cd_fare_basis|newColumnName|
+--------------------+-------------+
|              YX-1F2|           YX|
|              AB-0G1|           AB|
+--------------------+-------------+
```